Using Tabula Py Templates
I would like to use Tabula to extract data with the tabula templates. One template will be for the first page and another template for the rest of the pages. Both templates were generated using Tabula. How do I tweak the second on to work on the other pages dynamically. I tried removing the page key from the template but that doesn't work
Tried this so far:
[{
    "page": 2,
    "extraction_method": "lattice",
    "selection_id": "C1730288809732",
    "x1": 35.00013125000002,
    "x2": 559.34388125,
    "y1": 59.001687499999946,
    "y2": 717.2204375,
    "width": 524.34375,
    "height": 658.21875,
    "spec_index": 2
}]


